# Simple $\mathbb{C}[C_n]-$modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I want to show that there are exactly $n$ of those, up to isomorphism. Also they all have to be one-dimensional. The latter I know to be true, due to the fact that (as I know from another course about representations, which was *far* less abstract and never talked about modules) irreducible representations of an Abelian groups have dimension 1. I'm still having some trouble seeing the connection between these views. I see how you can get your group homomorphism $G \rightarrow$ Aut$_k(V)$ from a module structure, and vice versa. I feel like a lot of these statements should be easily translatable from one language ($k[G]$-modules) to the other (the group homomorphism).

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's pretty trivial using ring/module theory. $\mathbb C[C_n]$ is a semisimple ring (by Maschke's theorem) and commutative, therefore it is a finite product of finite field extensions of $\mathbb C$, all of which are necessarily $\mathbb C$. As a result, there are exactly $n$ copies of $\mathbb C$ as a $\mathbb C[C_n]$ module, mutually nonisomorphic as simple $\mathbb C[C_n]$ modules.  You're probably right that it has a straightforward translation, and I'd like to see that. Maybe you even can, using this sketch.

Comment: What is a field extension? (This course is a little over my head.. It was said that even Algebra 2 (Ring Theory) was no prerequisite, let alone Field Theory. Even though, yes, they did repeat the definitions of rings and modules, I've come to conclude that wasn't a very wise decision.)

Comment: Maybe this takes you part of the way: prove the regular representation is a finite product of its simple subrepresentations, then prove the summands in this product are necessarily distinct, then prove that every simple representation must appear as a subrepresentation of the regular representation.

Comment: A field extension is two fields $F,E$ such that $F\subseteq E$. Can you really be studying representation theory without knowing what a field extension is?  That's amazing!  I definitely had a basic course on Galois theory long before I heard of group representations.

Comment: Apparently... I know what the characteristic of a ring (and hence a field) is, and up to now that's about all we needed to know.. 
Thanks for the comment. I'll think about it.

Comment: (Skimmed your profile) I'm interested in some mathematical physics right now. Namely, Noether's theorems on invariance.

Comment: @rschwieb That’s one of my highest interests too!

Comment: I've spent a long time looking for a lower-level yet mathematically rigorous exposition, but I finally found the path forward.  Still on background material, though. It requires a lot of tools I never had the chance to learn.

Comment: The translation between representations (i.e. group homomorphisms $G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space) to $kG$ modules is quite straightforward, and essentially you just replace the word "representation" with "module". This translation itself does not really add much to understanding, but after making this translation you can take advantage of what is known about representations of finite-dimensional algebras over $k$, in terms of structure theorems and so on. Do you think this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Kind of, but I've since found out that the number of different $k[G]$-modules equal the number of $G$-conjugacy classes. As $C_n$ is Abelian, there are $n$ of these.